# access token google auth

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

When you access a Google API you have to authenticate, then you get the necessary tokens.

The access_token has an expiration time, but when I send requests with a null access_token (to receive an answer as if the token had expired I receive a status 200 response.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you add your code to see what is happening?

Comment: What is response you getting with 200

Comment: The code is 200 but the returned JSON possibly says something like `success: false`.

Comment: The JSON returns the data as expected. when I change the refresh token, and send a request there if I get error